# How to install Toolkit for Ruby for MacOS

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, tk-toolkit, rbenv

I need the Gem TK on my Mac with Mojave. I followed [a tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/docs/setup) that worked for a friend, but she can't explain how she did it anymore.

I installed:

- The CommandLine tool
- homebrew rbenv and ruby-build
- Ruby 2.6.2, which is used globally. (ruby -v => 2.6.2)
- rbenv init into the shell
- rbenv-doctor

But I can't get any further with:

```
$ bundle install
```

Neither using Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org' do
  gem 'tk'
end
```

nor without it:

```
$ sudo gem install tk
```

works. I get:

```
Warning:: cannot find X11 library. tcltklib will not be compiled (tcltklib is disabled on your Ruby. That is, Ruby/Tk will not work). Please check configure options. If your Tcl/Tk don't require X11, please try --without-X11.
```

I can't find X11 libraries. So I can't make tcltklib.so, which is required by Ruby/Tk. So I installed ActiveTCL and did:

```
$ sudo gem install tk
```

When I start the program, the toolkit opens, and my classes are visible, but I can't execute any methods. Everything is black. With my setup in Windwows, my programm runs perfectly.

Do you know why my toolkit doesn't run flawless?

Answer (score 3):

X11 is no longer shipped with macOS [[1]](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201341). If it is required by one of your libs, then you can try installing [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/). This message:

```
Warning:: cannot find X11 library. tcltklib will not be compiled
```

means, that X11 is required by `tk` gem.